# Display few text boxes one by one with delay using Threads

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, web-applications, asp.net-4.0

I'm a beginner with C#. I'm developing a web application using C#.net.

My question is, When I click a button, I need to display some text boxes in a web form one by one keeping some delay.
I have typed in the button click event like this;

```
textBox1.Text = C1.ToString();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    textBox2.Text = C2.ToString();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    textBox3.Text = C3.ToString();
    Thread.Sleep(5000);

    textBox4.Text = C4.ToString();
```

Here C1,C2,C3,C4 are integer variables which stored some values.
The output displays all 4 textboxes at once after (5000*3)=15000 time period(after 15 seconds).

**But actually I need them to display one by one after every 5 seconds.**
When I press the button, the textBox1 should display and the textBox2 should display after 5 second.
How can I do like that?
**Can I do this using threads?** Or please tell me a better way.
Please help me..

Comment: When a web page is rendered, it is rendered completely and sent back to the client.  To do any animation, you need to use Javascript on the client.

Comment: I am not expert in web, but i think it must be done at client side, i.e. by javascript.

Comment: you have set time interval for all your thread as 5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is send all the text boxes to the page but hide them in a `<div>` or `<span>` and set their style to `hidden`.  Then use some javascript with a delay to slowly show them one by one.

Here is a good little tutorial about hiding and showing elements on a web page in javascript.
http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/dom3.shtml

Here is how the javascript to delay the showing would work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function() {showText1()}, 5000);

    function showText1 () {
        //javascript to set textbox1's div/span to visible
        setTimeout(function() {showText2()}, 5000);
    }

    function showText2 () {
        //javascript to set textbox2's div/span to visible
        setTimeout(function() {showText3()}, 5000);
    }

    function showText3 () {
        //javascript to set textbox3's div/span to visible
    }
</script>
```